# Testnet account viewer?

Tags: testnet

I know there's an account viewer for Stellar - its here: https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/

AFAIK, this works for Livenet, not for Testnet. Is there a similar tool for testnet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm familiar with:

[Stellar Desktop client](http://wallet.stellar.chat/)
[StellarChain.io](http://testnet.stellarchain.io/)
And the [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&network=test), which is basically just a visual tool to interact with horizon

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can find the Stellar's own account viewer for test and live in their site.

Here is the link for test:

[TEST ACCOUNT VIEWER IN STELLAR](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&network=test)

The same you can find for live if you switch at upper right corner to Public or you can access from the link:

[LIVE ACCOUNT VIEWER IN STELLAR](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&network=public)